# How can I clone a object from live cycle designer with javascript scripting

Tags: javascript, livecycle, livecycle-designer

On the click event of a button I would like to clone an object say a text or better a sub form and put it under the existing one... I have searched google and I don't have any idea how to do this...please help

I want to do it in LiveCycleDesigner Adobe in the Java script language